# Akka Persistence Cassandra with Akka 2.3.0 throwing fatal EOFException when used with Play 2.2.1

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka, akka-persistence

Any idea why I am getting the following error after adding Akka to my library dependencies and executing the `test` task?

```
Uncaught error from thread [reactivemongo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[reactivemongo]
    akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2596)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1316)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at sbt.React.react(ForkTests.scala:116)
    at sbt.ForkTests$$anonfun$mainTestTask$1$Acceptor$2$.run(ForkTests.scala:75)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

And when I execute the `run` task:

```
Uncaught error from thread [reactivemongo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[reactivemongo]
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
[ERROR] [03/25/2014 15:28:17.309] [reactivemongo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [ActorSystem(reactivemongo)] Uncaught error from thread [reactivemongo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

My relevant `build.sbt` settings

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

// Dependencies

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Sonatype Releases" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases",
  "Krasser's Bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/krasserm/maven"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // akka
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-experimental" % "2.3.0",
  "com.github.krasserm" % "akka-persistence-cassandra_2.10" % "0.2",
  // dependency injection
  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0",
  "net.codingwell" % "scala-guice_2.10" % "4.0.0-beta",
  "javax.inject" % "javax.inject" % "1",
  // mongo
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo" % "0.10.0",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.2",
  // slick
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.166",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "1.0.1",
  // testing
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5" % "test",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.8" % "test",
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.11.3" % "test"
)

// App settings

play.Project.playScalaSettings
```

And my `project/plugin.sbt`

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
```

This started after I added the akka-persistence plugin with the following libs:

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.0",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-experimental" % "2.3.0",
"com.github.krasserm" % "akka-persistence-cassandra_2.10" % "0.2"
```

I installed Cassandra and I am running it locally while doing this.

Even if I comment any one of these lines out and run `sbt clean`, `sbt update`, and `sbt test` I still see this error. Only when I comment them all out am I able to run and test my app.

My only guess is that the version of Akka in the persistence library and Play2 are incompatible.

Does that sound right?

Comment: A similar question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779882/combining-akka-2-3-x-and-play-2-2-x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Play 2.2.x uses Akka 2.2.x.  You'll need to wait for Play 2.3 which will be compatible with Akka 2.3.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the issue. I tried to build Play from source to run the 2.3-SNAPSHOT, but I ran into an issue where the WS library was no longer accessible. I just reverted because I don't really have enough time to investigate. I'm just gonna see if I can use an older version of akka-persistence.

Comment: You'll have to step back to the old `eventsourced` library for Akka which is the predecessor of `akka-persistence`.  If you want to use the snapshot, know that WS was moved out of Play Core so you just need to add the dependency.