# Why is default Play app created in IDEA crashing at startup with Akka 2.3.3 declared as dependency?

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, akka, playframework-2.2

I created a new Play Framework 2 application using IntelliJ IDEA. The only things I changed in the default project were creating a Java controller `Application` instead of the default Scala controller (called the same) and adding Akka to the project.

Here is what my **build.sbt** build looks like:

```
import play.Project._

name := "ServerSide"

version := "1.0"

// the following line was added
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.3.3"

playScalaSettings
```

The project compiles fine, but when I'm starting it, it errors with a clearly Akka-specific error (it is in fact repeated about 5 times in the log):

```
[ERROR] [07/23/2014 15:27:57.462] [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [ActorSystem(play)] Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Removing Akka from `build.sbt` fixes the problem.

What is the reason of the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Which Play version are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [combining akka 2.3.x and play 2.2.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779882/combining-akka-2-3-x-and-play-2-2-x)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I copied **build.sbt** from a project created by `activator`, but the project created by Intellij Idea most likely used an earlier version of the framework, so it was uncompatible with Akka. Changing Akka version to 2.2.4 fixed my problem.

Comment: @AndreySarafanov Could you please add your comment as an answer and accept? It's going to give you bonus points for keeping SO clean. Thanks!

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I did it, thanks for the tip! Have to wait for two days to accept that answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that i came up with is:

I copied `build.sbt` from a project created by `activator`, but the project created by Intellij Idea most likely used an earlier version of the framework, so it was uncompatible with Akka. Changing Akka version to 2.2.4 fixed my problem.