# akka error : play framework (2.3.3) and spark (1.0.2)

Tags: playframework, apache-spark

I am trying to connect to Spark from Play framework.
Getting the following Akka error...

```
ERROR] [08/16/2014 17:12:05.249] [spark-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [ActorSystem(spark)] Uncaught fatal error from thread [spark-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down ActorSystem [spark]
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
  at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.akka$actor$dungeon$FaultHandling$$finishTerminate(FaultHandling.scala:210)
  at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.terminate(FaultHandling.scala:172)
  at akka.actor.ActorCell.terminate(ActorCell.scala:369)
  at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:462)
  at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
  at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
  at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
  at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

full exception trace : https://gist.github.com/sujee/ff14fd602b76314e693d

source code here : https://github.com/sujee/play-spark-test

I have also found this thread mentioning Akka in-compatibility
[How to run Play 2.2.x with Akka 2.3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779882/how-to-run-play-2-2-x-with-akka-2-3-x)

any suggestions?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(answering my own question, in case others are looking for a solution)

This is caused by Akka library mismatch.  Akka versions  2.2 and 2.3 are not binary compatible

spark (v1.0.0, v1.0.2) uses  :  akka 2.2.3-shaded-protobuf

Play framework uses the following
play v2.2.0 ,   v2.2.2 ,  v2.2.3   uses  akka 2.2.0
play v2.3.3  uses  akka 2.3.4

In my case I used play 2.2.3 with Spark 1.0.2